# Activate the buttons only for the one who created the post

Tags: symfony, twig

In my case I have an article and users can comment on this article, I wanted each user to have the delete button just for his comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to add a column to your Comment table named user which has a one to many relationship with your User table (one user can have many comments). Then within your twig template where you render the commented you would do something like:

```
{% if app.user == comment.user() %}
//html for delete button
{% endif %}
```

Don't forget to verify this again in your controller before you actually delete anything.

https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/association-mapping.html